# creating a project management web application in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

In sharepoint , i have to create a web application that has an option to add new customer. delete customer. for each customer there should be option to add project , delete project. for each project there should be an option to add task assign task to different operators.

I am using MOSS 2007 evaluation verstion. Uptill now i have created a new web application, created site collection chose blank site as template, created shared services. what should i do next ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on whether you want it entirely in SharePoint or whether you are simply surfacing another system via SharePoint. For example, your clients and projects may be in SharePoint lists or they may be held in another database entirely and just displayed in SharePoint via web parts. Both are valid approaches depending on your requirements.

Assuming you want it in SharePoint, Microsoft has released 40 application templates that you can install to show you how they have approached certain problems, project tracking being one of them. Maybe this will help get you started.

You can [get the templates here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx)